# How To Show Node Comment Count in node.tpl?

Tags: theming, comments

I have had the bright idea of changing my user permissions so as guests cannot see the comments on a node. I have no problems with Views around my site, as they can clearly see there are comments on nodes, and they will be more inclined to register. The problem seems to be when they arrive on my site directly to a node, they don't see any comment, and think "that's a bit crap; let's go."

Is there a way I could show the amount of comments below a node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you use [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6).
This is a basic example for D8

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['comment_count'] = $variables['node']->get('YOUR_COMMENT_FIELD')->comment_count;
}
```

And then you can use it in your `node.html.twig` file like so:

```
{{ comment_count }}
```

A basic example in D6 is below, you can customize it to your liking.  In your template.php file located in your theme directory, add something along the lines of (replacing YOURTHEME with the name of your theme):

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $nid = $variables['node']->nid;
  $variables['num_comments'] = db_result(db_query('SELECT COUNT(cid) AS count FROM {comments} WHERE nid = %d', $nid)) . ' comment(s) on this node';
}
```

and save the file.  Now in node.tpl.php (or any equivalent template, node-mycontenttype.tpl.php, etc) simply add:

`<?php print $num_comments; ?>`

Wherever you would like the comment count to be located and save.  **Clear the cache** and then view your changes.

Comment: I have tried to adapt your code for the template_preprocess_node to drupal 7 but I am getting this error  Notice: Undefined variable: num_comments in include() (line 116

Comment: What have you changed while adapting? Does your database query look like the one given by @doterobcn below?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `$comment_count` in [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/6).

> `$type`: Node type, i.e. story, page, blog, etc.
>   `$comment_count`: Number of comments attached to the node.

Comment: I suppose that `$comment_count` counts the number of comments visible to the user; if the current user cannot see comments, that variable would be set to zero.

Comment: Yes. And more directly `$node->comment_count`

Answer (score 4):

Update, for Drupal 7 your query on template.php should look like:

```
$vars['num_comments'] = db_query("SELECT COUNT(cid) AS count FROM {comment} WHERE nid =:nid",array(":nid"=>$vars['nid']))->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 use this directly in your node template:

```
{{ node.comment.comment_count }}
```

Note that for it to work you need to have the default comment field in your node which is always named comment.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $nid = $variables['node']->nid->value;
  $num_comment = db_query('SELECT comment_count FROM {comment_entity_statistics} WHERE entity_id = ' . $nid)->fetchAssoc();
  $variables['comment_count'] = $num_comment['comment_count'];
}
```

Now in page.html.twig:

```
{{ comment_count }}
```

Clear the cache and then view your changes.

Comment: It is really bad practive yo query the db like that for something that can be doine a lot simpler using the Drupal API: $variables['node']->get('comment')->comment_count;

Comment: @ipwa if you know the comment field name, otherwise it's not a solution