# VIEW COUNT comments total per node

Tags: views, comments

I have found code to show the total:

[How To Show Node Comment Count in node.tpl?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8582/how-to-show-node-comment-count-in-node-tpl)

Unfortunately I need to have this value available via VIEWS because I want to list 5 nodes based on total comment count. Short of caching the total as a field in the node (intercepting comment post and incrementing the number) -- what are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a field available in views called "Comment count" - just add this field and your done.

[image]