# How to display comment sequence number inside node?

Tags: 7, comments

I want to display comment sequence number as permalink.
The question is: **how to count comments** in particular node and then display sequential number of every comment?
I'm talking about Drupal 7.

Comment: Check this. This may help you, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108328/view-count-comments-total-per-node

Comment: thank you for tip, but this is for views
i need to count comments programmatically